# Compress ls result using tar

Tags: shell-script, logs, compression

I want to compress log files by specific months.
Listing all files with following commands

```
ll | grep 'Sep' | grep 'oim_server'
```

Then I need to compress with tar result of it
How can I do it?

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do. And the 'Sep' and 'oim_server' strings are part of the logfile name ? Also, you want to compress the files individually, or you want to tar all files from one month together ?

Comment: Aim is to compress log files which are created in September and contains oim_server. " ll | grep 'Sep' | grep 'oim_server'  " provieds what i want. Then i need to compress

Comment: you did not answered my questions. You have just repeated what you said before.

Comment: Want to tar all files from one month together

Comment: oim_server is part of files name, sep is from created date

Comment: Please add those clarifications to your question. Don't leave them in the comments as it simply adds confusion ("which is more correct, the question or some changes in the comments?").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all the files modified in september :

```
find . -type f -newermt 2016-09-01 ! -newermt 2016-10-01
```

Append a file to an archive :

```
tar -rvf archive.tar filename
```

Now combine the two using exec :

```
find . -type f -newermt 2016-09-01 ! -newermt 2016-10-01 -exec tar -rvf logs_sept.tar {} +
```

Comment: I think you could also create the archive at once by ending the exec param by `{} +` instead of `{} \;` to use results as the parameters of a single `tar` call

Comment: That's right, I'm editing the answer. However depending on the number of files, `find` may still call `tar` multiple times. Thus `tar -r` is still needed.

Comment: Oh also, you haven't implemented the "filename to archive must contain oim_server" requirement, I suppose you should add a `-name` check

Comment: That only archives the files for September for 2016, not other years. That also doesn't compress them. (though it may actually be doing what the OP wanted as opposed to what he asked for)

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to archive the non-hidden files (of any type including directory) last-modified in September of any year and whose name contains `oim_server` (which looks like the intent of your `ll | grep 'Sep' | grep 'oim_server'` command though that one would also match on user/group/filename/symlink target containing `Sep` or `oim_server`), on a GNU system, you could do:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' \
       -name '*oim_server*' -printf '%Tm:%p\0' |
  sed -zn 's/^09://p' |
  tar --null --no-recursion -T - -cvvf - |
  xz > file.tar.xz
```

(`--no-recursion` being to *not* also archive the content of those directories last-modified in some September month).

Note that `tar` doesn't compress, it just archives (lumps files with data and metadata together onto a tape or file so they can be restored as-is later). You pipe its output to a compressor like `xz` above to obtain a compressed archive. Some `tar` implementations like GNU `tar` can call those compressors by themselves (`-J`/`--xz` for `xz` compression in recent versions of GNU `tar`).

If you wanted to archive the files that show-up in the output of your filtered `ls`, you'd do:

```
ll | grep Sep | grep oim_server |
  awk '{print $NF}' |
  tar  --no-recursion -T - -cvvf - |
  xz > file.tar.xz
```

Which you can simplify to:

```
ll | awk '/Sep/ && /oim_server/ {print $NF}' |
  tar  --no-recursion -T - -cvvf - |
  xz > file.tar.xz
```

However note that it has quite a few limitations:

- The `grep Sep` searches for `Sep` on the whole line, not just the month field. That includes the user and group name, the file name and the target of symlinks.
- `Sep` will be used for files last modified in September only in some English locales.
- like for `Sep` above the `oim_server` could be found anywhere on the line
- file names can contain newline characters, so assuming that a file name is only on one line is wrong in the general case.
- worse, `awk '{print $NF}'` prints the last word of each line. That means it won't work for file names containing blanks or for symlinks (where it will output the last word of the target of the symlink instead)